# Range works in formula but not in custom function

Tags: vba, excel-formula, range

I have a range in a formula and it works:

> =MAX(LN(A2:A7))

[image]

Now I want to rebuild this formula as a custom function and it does not work.

```
Function testy(xr As Range)
    n = WorksheetFunction.Max(WorksheetFunction.Ln(xr))
    testy = n   
End Function
```

It throws an error: wrong datatype. But I defined "As Range"?
Why does it not work, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application.Ln`.

The issue is that `WorksheetFunction.Ln` accepts a `Double` as its argument. You're implicitly passing it the `.Value` of a multi-cell range, which is a `Variant` array.

Using the late-bound `Application.Ln`, one can pass an array (and get an array back):

```
Function testy(ByVal xr As Range) As Double
    testy = WorksheetFunction.Max(Application.Ln(xr))
End Function
```

[image]